# Stop scanf loop if user enters a specific number (Not working) C

Tags: c, loops, compare, scanf

I've looked at multiple solutions but none of them worked for me.

I'm asking the user to enter numbers in a loop, but if the user enters a specific number the loop should break.

This is what I've got so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXNUMBERS 5

int getNumbers(int array[])
{
  int i;
  int n = 0;
  printf("Enter max. %d numbers, enter empty line to end:\n", MAXNUMBERS);

  for (i = 0; i < MAXNUMBERS; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    fflush(stdin);
    n++;
    if (array[i] == '5')
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  return n;
}

int main()
{
  int array[MAXNUMBERS];
  int amount_numbers;
  amount_numbers = getNumbers(array);

  printf("Numbers entered: %d\n", amount_numbers);
  printf("First three: %d %d %d", array[0], array[1], array[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

- Input:

  ```
  1  
  5  
  4  
  3  
  2
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  Numbers entered: 5  
  First three: 1 5 4
  ```

If the user enters `5` the loop should break.

I'm using 5 as an example, I later want it to do with an empty line. But it doesn't even work with `5`.

It just keeps prompting the user to enter another number after he entered `5`.

Comment: If I later do this when I entered 9 first:  
`if (array[0] == 9)  
  {  
    printf("Success\n");  
  }`  

It works.

So the error must lie somewhere else.

Comment: fflush(stdin) is undefined behavior. Don't use it.

Comment: Suggestion what I could use instead? I want to prevent the user from entering multiple numbers at once.

Someone below has an explanation.

Comment: @LorenzLeitner you mean `2` digits or `2` integers?

Comment: Two integers, like if the user enters `5 3` and then presses enter. (With the space between `5` and `3`.

I think that would cause trouble with scanf.

But I will use your method below @iharob.

Comment: You can use `fgets()` and `strtol()` to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (array[i] == '5')
```

You're checking whether `array[i]` is equal to the [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com) of the **character** `'5'`.

Remove the `''` to make it compare against the integer `5`.

Comment: Yes, I _just_ realized!

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem is `'5' != 5` the former is the character `5` which is in fact it's ascii value, and the latter is the number `5`, since you are reading integers, i.e. using the `"%d"` specifier in `scanf()` you should use `5`, but it would be better if it was just a `int` variable, and you could initialize it to any number you like before the loop starts.

Your loop is wrong anyway because if the user enters a non-numeric value then your program will invoke undefined behavior. Besides you already invoke undefined behavior with `fflush(stdin)`, so

**Remove `fflush(stdin)`**<sup>1</sup>

> **7.21.5.2 The `fflush` function**
>
> 2. If stream points to an **output stream** or an **update** stream *in which the most recent operation was **not** input*, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
>      undefined.

So the behavior is **undefined** for an input stream like `stdin`, or even if the most recent operation was input.

You must check that the value was read properly, and then check in the loop condition if it equals the value you want to stop the loop with, try this

```
int readNumber()
{
    int value;
    printf("input a number > ");
    while (scanf("%d", &value) == 1)
    {
        int chr;
        printf("\tinvalid input, try again...\n");
        do { /* this, will do what you thought 'fflush' did */
            chr = getchar();
        } ((chr != EOF) && (chr != '\n'));
        printf("input a number > ");
    }
    return value;
}

int getNumbers(int array[])
{
  int i;
  int stop = 5;

  printf("Enter max. %d numbers, enter empty line to end:\n", MAXNUMBERS);

  array[0] = 0;
  for (i = 0 ; ((i < MAXNUMBERS) || (array[i] == stop)) ; i++)
    array[i] = readNumber();

  return i;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This is a quote from the C11 draft 1570.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, wish I could upvote.

Are these two functions connected or are these just options?

EDIT: I just realized getNumbers() calls readNumber(), my bad.

Comment: @LorenzLeitner which functions?

Comment: Thank you for this extensive answer, I will look into it and try to make it work like this.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if an integer is equal to the character '5', which is then being cast to an ascii value of '5'.

Try using this:

`if (array[i] == 5)`

Comment: Yes, I just realized! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Disregard everything!

I should have written

```
if (array[i] == 5)
```

without the quotes!

I'm an idiot!

I sat 2 hours at this error...